# Editing bmp pixel by pixel [C++]

Tags: c++, pixel, fstream, bmp

I want to make a program that will take an image and replace the Blue component of every pixel with 0.

So I wrote this. I have one bmp image in the folder and a copy of it and as the input file i put in the name of the original and as the output name i write the copy. But when i try to open the second one after the program works it doesnt open properly. Could anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ofstream ofs;
    char input[80];
    char output[80];

    cout<<"Input file name"<<endl;
    cin>>input;
    ifs.open(input, ios::binary);

    if(!ifs)
    {
        cout<<"Error in opening file"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    cout<<"Output file name"<<endl;
    cin>>output;
    ofs.open(output, ios::binary);

    ifs.seekg(2);

    int file_size;
    ifs.read((char*)&file_size, sizeof(int));

    ofs<<"Bitmap size: "<<file_size<<"\r\n";

    ifs.seekg(10);
    int beg;
    ifs.read((char*)&beg, sizeof(int));

    ofs<<"Beggining of image: "<<beg<<"\r\n";

    ifs.seekg(18);
    int columns;
    ifs.read((char*)&columns, sizeof(int));

    ofs<<"Column number: "<<columns<<"\r\n";

    ifs.seekg(22);
    int rows;
    ifs.read((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));

    ofs<<"Row number: "<<rows<<"\r\n";

    int image_size=0;
    columns+=(3*columns)%4;
    image_size=3*columns*rows;

    ofs<<"Size of image"<<image_size<<"\r\n";

    ifs.seekg(beg);

    unsigned char R,G,B;
    for(int i=beg; i<image_size+beg; i+=3)
    {
        ofs.seekp(i);
        ofs<<char(0);
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what is happening if your program just copy the file - write bytes from input to output without modification?

Comment: What about the for almost at the end of the code?

Comment: Piotr - no I haven't but that's a good idea. I will

Comment: I don't know much about BMP format, but... does it really contains strings such a "Size of image" or "Row number: "?

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski no, of course it does not.

Comment: Even when  I just copy the file from one bmp to another it doesn't work. Yes it does :) there is such information in the header of the file :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no image file format that contains text like "Bitmap size: ", "Beginning of image: ", "Column number: ", "Row number: ", and "Size of image".

Even if there was such a file format, you are not writing "Beginning", you are writing "Beggining", and that would not work.  Computers tend to be very partial to proper spelling.

Even if there was such a file format, it would not be the same as the file format that you are reading, because you are reading an `int` at offset 2 and interpreting it as some kind of file size, but you are not writing any size at offset 2 of your output file.

So, to cut a long story short, you have to have a very clear specification of the file format you are reading, (which you have told us nothing about,) and you also have to follow this exact same specification in writing the file.

Making up your own file format specification as you go along will not work.

Also, in the future, keep in mind that on stackoverflow, phrases like "it doesnt open properly" are not considered valid descriptions of technical issues.  Be specific about precisely what is happening.

Hint: you appear to be trying to edit the file in-place, by seeking to individual bytes and overwriting them with zero. That won't work on an empty file.  Copy the entire contents of the original file to the new filename, and then go seeking and overwriting bytes on the copy.

Comment: This is an assignment I got in class and in the description it says that for example the size of the bmp file is at offset 2, the beggining of the image in the file is given at offset 10 etc. And it works, because it reads all of the information properly.

Sorry, when i wrote "doesn't open properly" I meant that when I try to open the file with the default windows image viewer its says "windows can't open the image".

Comment: The new filename is the copy of the bmp, so I'm not operating on an empty file.  I have one that I read from and another one that I'm trying to change by seeking to individual bytes and replacing them with zero.

Comment: Mateusz, you are prompting the user to enter one filename for the input file, and another filename for the output file, so clearly, you are working with two different files.  You are *not* making any attempt whatsoever to copy the contents of the input file into the output file, so you *are* operating on a file which must be presumed to be empty.  (It may happen to already exist, but that's irrelevant.)  If your code relies on the prior existence of the output file, then you would have absolutely no use for an input file.

Comment: I have to apologize for writing "copy the original file to the new filename", because that is unclear.  A file cannot be copied to a filename. What I meant, of course, is "copy the contents of the input file into the output file".

Answer (score 1):

So I'll post my comment as answer:
I don't know much about BMP format, but... does it really contains strings such a "Size of image" or "Row number: "?

If not, remove `ofs<<"Beggining of image: "<<beg<<"\r\n";` etc., I think that you meant `cout` instead of `ofs`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in stead of reading a file to modify I just copy the whole content of the original file to the output file name and modify that. Thanks guys, and thanks Mike, I did that at your suggestion.

Comment: Mateusz, this should be a comment, not an answer.